# SQL with SUBSTRING / CHARINDEX

Tags: strings, sql, t-sql

I've got a `VARCHAR` variable of this kind:

```
@string = "BLABLA10;GOGOGO30;RES777;ANOTHER;"
```

(several keyword + number separated by `;`)

I need to get the `INT` value after `"RES"` in a T-SQL query (using SYBASE).

I thought it would be always 3 characters, so I did:

```
SELECT @val = CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(";RES", @string)+4, 3))))
```

But now, it can be 2 characters (or more) for example... so I need to get the value between `RES` and the next `;`

I've done a complicated query:

```
CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(";RES", @string)+4, -4 + CHARINDEX(";", SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(";RES", @string)+1, 70) )))))
```

It works but it's horrible to read.

Has anyone an idea for a more readable way than this?

I know that the real problem is that we should not use value in concatenated string, but well it was done that way and I can't change it.

Comment: Sadly, that looks about right. You could hide it away in a UDF, but performance would suffer.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the nail on the head there:

> I know that the real problem is that we should not use value in concatenated string, but well it was done that way and I can't change it.

So you are in a situation where you have to over-compensate on the database end to counter a bad design decision. Many of us who write SQL regularly in production environments have been there. So let's see what we can do about it.

---

I have added new lines and indentations to give a better scope of what your string manipulation query is doing:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'BLABLA10;GOGOGO30;RES777;ANOTHER;';
SELECT 
    CONVERT(
        INT, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(
            SUBSTRING(
                @string, 
                CHARINDEX(
                    ';RES', 
                    @string
                )+4, 
                -4 + CHARINDEX(
                    ';', 
                    SUBSTRING(
                        @string, 
                        CHARINDEX(
                            ';RES', 
                            @string
                        )
                        +1, 
                        70
                    ) 
                )
            )
        ))
    )
;
```

*Note: I have converted `"`s to `'`s so I could run it on SQL Server.*

This is quite complicated. You've obviously spent a good amount of time putting this together so it would work. I'd say, to avoid **WTF**s from Mr. or Ms. Maintainer, you should document it.

---

#### Inspired by RegEx verbose

There's a regular expression mode in some programming languages that lets you document your regular expression. Since your SQL does similar things than RegEx does, I figured maybe we could find inspiration there. For example sake, this is a documented verbose RegEx from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE):

> ```
> a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
>                    \.    # the decimal point
>                    \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
> ```

Let's try and do something similar here, starting with the innermost manipulation:

```
SUBSTRING(  -- get keyword RES and the chars that follow (up to 70 chars max)
    @string, 
    CHARINDEX(      -- find index of 
        ';RES',     -- semicolon just before keyword RES
        @string     -- in @string
    )
    +1,         -- +1 to advance past the semicolon
    70          -- length of up to 70
```

So it starts making a bit of sense for the next person. Let's keep working our way up the chain from there:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'BLABLA10;GOGOGO30;RES777;ANOTHER;';
SELECT 
    /*
    The purpose of this manipulation is to find 
    get the value between RES and the next ;
    in a string of keywords and numbers. (referred to as @string)
    NOTE: Read function documentation from inner to outer to understand how this works.
    */
    CONVERT(
        INT,    -- returned value needs to be an integer
        LTRIM(RTRIM(    -- trim potential white space before or after the value
            SUBSTRING(      -- String of characters between end of RES and following semicolon
                @string,        -- in @string
                CHARINDEX(      -- find index of
                    ';RES',     -- keyword RES and semicolon just before it
                    @string     -- in @string
                )+4,        -- add 4 chars to move index just past RES keyword
                -4 + CHARINDEX( -- find index of
                    ';',        -- semicolon after the value belonging with RES
                    SUBSTRING(      -- String of keyword RES and the chars that follow (up to 70 chars max)
                        @string, 
                        CHARINDEX(      -- find index of 
                            ';RES',     -- semicolon just before keyword RES
                            @string     -- in @string
                        )
                        +1,         -- +1 to advance past the semicolon
                        70          -- length of up to 70 chars
                    ) 
                )
            )
        ))
    )
;
```

Looking at it now, there are already a few things that stand out:

---

#### Length 70?

Do you *really* need to capture `RES` and up to ***70*** characters? You are converting the string to a signed 4-byte `int` which will at most be 2,147,483,647 (10 digits). So, just to be safe, let's factor in the keyword `RES`, and the following `;`, and one extra for good luck. So let's change 70 to 15.

```
SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(";RES", @string)+1, 15) )
```

If you needed to change the outermost `CONVERT` to say, a `BIGINT`, then you would need a longer string, but that seems not to be the case based on your code.

---

#### `LTRIM(RTRIM(`

I know that SQL operators often include this *"just in case"*, so I don'tblame you for doing so. But since you're seeking a review, I will point out that perhaps you should think of what are the chances of this actually happening?

To illustrate, a use case of this happening would look perhaps like this:

> ```
> @string = "BLABLA10;GOGOGO30;RES   777  ;ANOTHER;"
> ```

If that is not possible, then you may as well just remove the `LTRIM(RTRIM(` part altogether. *In fact*, it looks like converting to int already does that for you, so just remove it.

Demo:

> ```
> SELECT CONVERT(INT, '   777  ')
> -- Result: 777
> ```

*Note: If you do expect that empty spaces will be present, you may need to adjust the `15` value above (instead of `70`) to a higher number to account for this.*

---

#### Speaking of RegEx...

Did you consider using Regular Expressions instead of this complicated manipulation? Here are a few links for you to consider:

- Create a UDF to support [Regular Expressions in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/khen1234/regular-expressions-in-t-sql)
- StackOverflow: [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

If you supported RegEx it may be as simple as just search for `(?<=RES)(.*)(?=;)` instead of doing this whole mammoth maneuver.